# How to continue map loop on exception?

Tags: javascript

Here is my code.

```
async function test(){

try{
   const result = //await "database query1"
   result.map(async item => {
   try{
      //await "database query2"
   }catch(e){
      //If code reaches here the whole map function ends even if there are more item in result 
   }
  }catch(e){
     //handle "database query1"
  }
}
```

How do I continue map function until all the array items ends ?

Comment: Use for or for of loop if you want to use await inside

Comment: I hope that's not your real code, since it's syntactically incorrect.

Comment: `.map()` will not stop if you get a rejected promise inside. You'll get a full array of promises out of it but one (or more) might be rejected. It's hard to say what's the best way to handle this as I sincerely doubt that's your real code.

Comment: My real code has lot of queries so this is simplified pseudo query. The main concern is why the control gets out of map in error even when it is handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I was facing this because some of the query of `try` inside the `map` didn't have `await`. I am not sure why this happens but looks like we need await in every case which returns promise in order for catch to work as expected.

Answer (score 4):

You may be looking for something like this, to run query 2 in parallel on all items, while swallowing any errors that may occur.

```
async function test() {
  const result = await database.query("query1");
  const results = await Promise.all(
    result.map(async (item) => {
      try {
        return await database.query("query2", item);
      } catch (e) {
        return null; // Maybe log the error?
      }
    }),
  );
  return results;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a misuse of `.map()`.  You're not actually mapping anything, returning nothing from the function and assigning no result.  It looks like you're just looking for a loop:

```
for (let item of result) {
    try {
        // await "database query2"
        // etc.
    } catch(e) {
        // handle the exception in some way
    }
}
```

As long as "handling the exception" doesn't involve ending the loop or exiting that part of the stack in any way, the loop will continue.